# how to make notification in vuejs for mobile app with device id?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins

I have an issue with Firebase notifications (FCM) and `VueJS`. I am unable to figure out how to retrieve the device ID from the phone.

I have tried with various plugins such as `cordova-plugin-firebase` but I am still unable to get the device id.

Can someone point me to the  direction eventually with a codesnippet.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with **UUID**:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceuuid

Other alternative Is the imei code:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-imei